# ヒストグラムの階級を500区切りにしたい

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

下記のコードを書いてみました

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'value': [
            5060,5000, 4400, 4001,2500, 1100, 1000, 900, 800,
            500,453,392,380,296,207,160,130,100,41,40,32,31,26,25,15,10,9,7
        ]
    }
)

ax = sns.histplot(df["value"], kde=False)
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(1))
plt.show()
```

結果:
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

横軸である階級の`1000`や`4000`, `5000`あたりに描画されたグラフが、キリの良い数字からはみ出ています。

[Pythonのseabornで手軽なのに美しいヒストグラムを作成する方法 | たぬハック](https://tanuhack.com/seaborn-histgram/)
や
[matplotlibやseabornのヒストグラムでビン幅をサクッとキレイに整える](https://qiita.com/matyubara/items/4137acf9cfbdc1dcbab7)

を参考に `bins`　を設定すればいいのかと思ったのですが、`bins`は、何等分するのかという考え方のようで、`500`ごとに分割するという考え方とは違うようです。特定数値ごとに分割するという書き方がわからないので、やみくもに`10`や`11`をあたえるといい感じにきりのよい500で区切ってくれるかと思いましたが、そんなことはありませんでした。特定数値ごとに分割するということはできないのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`binwidth=`引数でbinの幅を指定できます。
おそらくこちらがご希望に沿ったものでしょうか。
幅を指定するだけでなく区切りの位置を500の倍数に確実に合わせたい場合は
`binrange=`引数の指定を併用します。

```py
ax = sns.histplot(df["value"], kde=False, binwidth=500, binrange=(0,5500))
```

また、`bins=`引数は区切りのリストも受け付けます。ですので

```py
ax = sns.histplot(df["value"], kde=False, bins=range(0,6000,500))
```

みたいにしても500ずつ区切りにできます。